# Convert Raw Hdd Image From S3 Bucket to EC2 Image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have raw hdd image in s3 bucket.
I would like to convert that image and deploy vm from that image i EC2 with boto3 or python.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS VM Import documentation is at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/.

It explains the pre-requisites and the steps needed to import a VM.

The awscli supports [import-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html) and boto3 supports [import_volume](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.import_volume).

Comment: I read that. Requirements are met. Any code that I can use to import vm?